# Is it common for Commonwealth legislation to share the same name?

Tags: legislation

I'm nonplussed that two Acts of UK Parliament share same name! I think this was deliberate?  Parliamentary draftsmen or Counsel or Law Commissioner, UK Parliament couldn't have all overlooked the same name!

Why not name the 1984 Act differently to distinguish from 1957 Act? The 1984 Act can be named more specifically like Occupiers' Liability for Trepassers Act 1984?

Why doesn't 1984 Act just repeal 1957 Act, and copy and paste with modifications 1957 Act in the 1984 Act? Then no need for 1957 Act.

My nonplus is broader than just these two Acts. In the main, do Commonwealth primary and secondary legislation regularly share the same name? What are pros and cons? This book is for UK law students, but the author's American and is now Associate Prof. at Sydney University.

> Your lecturers and textbook will help you identify those sections
> of the statute that are particularly important, so you will, of course,
> focus on those aspects in your studies. When you read cases discussing
> a piece of legislation, be sure you know which statute or
> portions of the statute are at issue; it usually doesn’t help you, for
> example, **to cite a case discussing the Occupiers’ Liability Act 1957
> when the question is directing you to an analysis of the Occupiers’
> Liability Act 1984**. You must pay particular attention to the precise
> language of a statute, even more so than in a judicial opinion. While
> judicial opinions can and do use terms of art, language is especially
> important in statutory analysis because Parliament has spent a great
> deal of time debating the language of the statute. Therefore, avoid
> paraphrasing statutes and instead use the exact terms in your notes
> as well as in your essays and examination papers (though see the caution
> against lengthy quotations in chapter four).

Stacie Strong. [B.A. English literature (UC Davis 1986), MPW (USC 1990), J.D. (Duke 1994), PhD Law (Cambridge 2002), DPhil (Oxford 2003)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/s-i-strong-50b82832/). *How to Write Law Essays & Exams* 5th Edition (2018), p 11.

Comment: This would seem to be more of a legal question than a political one. To fully repeal and replace rather than update would be a matter of legal form, similarly specifying the same name for a replacement or addendum act would probably be covered by professional practices stemming from the legal profession rather than a political choice. Happy to be shown I'm wrong though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parliament has put out a lot of legislation over the years, and some from the 1800s is still in force. Trying to give everything a unique name would simply make it less natural; it would end up like the *Fast And Furious* film franchises' increasingly ridiculous names.

The question of whether any particular law will be "consolidated", ie entirely replace the old one with a new text, depends on how big the changes are. [Companies Act 2006 is consolidated, for example.](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/46/contents)

Personally I prefer it to the [French system,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cite_French_law) where the date of enactment comes first and is the most important aspect - often you'll see simply references to "law of (date)" with no further explanation. Easy to look up in an index, not so easy to remember.

> do Commonwealth primary and secondary legislation regularly share the same name

(I think) Both of the Occupiers’ Liability Acts are primary legislation, secondary legislation is regulations made without the full parliamentary procedure and tends not to contain the word "Act".